# How can I get content length from responses header?

Tags: java, android, httpconnection

I'm using this code for fetching data from a URL using `AsyncTask`:

```
 protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    int ResponseCode=-1;
    try {
        URL myURL=new URL("URL...");
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        ResponseCode=connection.getResponseCode();

        if (ResponseCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
            Reader reader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int contentLength=connection.getContentLength();
            char[] charArray=new char[contentLength];
            reader.read(charArray);
            String responseData=new String(charArray);
            Log.i("TAG", responseData);
            Log.i("TAG", ""+contentLength);
        }
        else {
            Log.i("TAG", " Unsuccessful HTTP Response Code: "+ResponseCode);
        }

    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "MalformedURLException Error: "+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "IOException Error: "+e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Exception Error: "+e);
    }
    return " "+ResponseCode;
}
```

above code works fine and I use it in some projects, but for URL that I'm working on, it doesn't work and always return -1 for `Response Code`,[because the HTTP response of my URL doesn't contain `Content-Length` header, the content is chunked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089953/httpconnection-javax-microedition-returning-1-for-getlength-method), now I wanna know Is there any equivalent way to do that?
**Thanks in advanced**

Comment: **"...Is there any equivalent way to do that?"** : Quite simply, no. Unless you download the whole thing and check the length afterwards there's no way. The only slight possibility is if you are in control of the server-side code and you add `Content-Length` response or some othe way of querying the length.

Comment: Thanks, but server isn't in my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved my problem this way :

```
try {
     URL blogPostURL=new URL("URL...");
     URLConnection connection=blogPostURL.openConnection();
     BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
     String responseData;
     while ((responseData = reader.readLine()) != null){ 
             Log.i("TAG", responseData);
     }
     reader.close();
}catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     Log.i("TAG", "MalformedURLException Error: "+e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
     Log.i("TAG", "IOException Error: "+e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
     Log.i("TAG", "Exception Error: "+e);
}
```

Comment: Which is to say that you decided you do not care about the length? Also, this code assumes that the response is in the default character encoding of the OS. You should look at the Content-Type value in the header of the response to determine the character encoding. You can use http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html from guava to help parse out the charset attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Following the http specs, if the content type is chunked the content length can be read on the stream after the header "Transfer-Encoding". It looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 May 2014 21:17:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

5F
```

Here the "5F" is the length in hex of the http response from that point on (in this case 95 bytes).

Notice that there is a newline after the Header and before the length.

For more info:

Easy explanation of http protocol :http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1c2
RFC (the official, complete one):https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616